# How to constantly check for a change in PHP?

Tags: php, input, server, stream, reload

I think my general understand of how php works is flawed. I read somewhere that php works line by line. However, when using things like php://input, this allows me to constantly check for a change in real time. But how can this be if php works line by line? Also, if I check for a variable change using something like

`if (isset ($_POST["url"], $_POST["message"])){`

then once the server receives the $_POST variables, it will carry out the if condition. Again, how does this happen if the if condition is only checked one time in the script run? Clearly php is not line by line.

Now onto my real question. How do I get this constant change check in PHP for other things? Like, inside the if statement I just showed you, I have a variable change to true. When this variable is true, then another if statement, later on in the script, should fire. However, it does not, as I am assuming the line-by-line nature of php is preventing it from constantly checking the state of this variable.

Maybe I am going off on a complicated tangent, but I just need things cleared up. Thanks.

Edit: I am using webhooks to make a messenger bot.

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

That is how I listen in on the stream.

Comment: No, PHP Is not an interpreted language, it does not work line by line; each file is compiled to bytecode as it is included, and then processed sequentially

Comment: why does PHP need to check constantly? its a server side language, so the only real way to do it is to keep hitting it with an AJAX call. Why not write some javascript to do what you want then have the PHP process it after it POSTs

Comment: @Mark Baker What does that mean? if it is processed sequentially then how can it constantly check for i/o streams?

Comment: @SaggingRufus How would I do that?

Comment: again, why does PHP need to do the checking? I am by no means recommending that you use AJAX for this. That is just the only way for the client side browser to interact with the server.

Comment: also PHP doesn't constantly look for IO streams it runs when it is called.

Comment: Well I actually want to do some server side stuff. And I use php://input to constantly check for the webhooks updates. See im making a messenger bot, and as soon as a message is received, php will process the json and send a message off without having to reload the page to check for anything new.

Comment: Better start learning AJAX my friend

Comment: @RyanVincent No actually! I don't really care if it goes to the browser or not, I just care about it running on the server.

Comment: and php://input and $_POST both seem to be constantly checking if im not wrong

Comment: PHP doesn't sit there and wait until it receives POST variables in the code you've provided. When you load that snippet of code, it will execute it. If at the time of execution the POST variables aren't set, it will skip to the 'else' clause of that 'if' statement (if it's defined). To run the code again, you would need to reload the page / re-execute the code. It won't sit there on that line waiting for $_POST to be available.

Comment: That's not what happens on my cloud9 server? I have the server constantly running, and only when the $_POST['url'] variable is set will the condition trigger. This heavily implies it is sitting there waiting for the variable to be set? I promise I am not reloading the page or restarting execution. Does PHP auto loop back to the start of index once the script has finished execution?

Comment: It uses facebook's graph api and webhooks! It does not accept user input! It gets the user message through their api and seems to able to constantly check for it

Comment: ok I made some edits.

Answer (score 0):

A webhook is an HTTP call and therefore your POST data is not going to 'change' because if your data changes, that necessitates a new HTTP POST which would be handled by a new execution of your PHP code.  So writing logic to look for changes in POST data is really irrelevant because those values are passed into your code.

Unless I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: And also, how does webhooks work with php if it doesn't constantly check for updates?? Doesn't make sense

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me...I promise I am not executing the script. All I have is the if isset condition I showed you in the original post. the $_POST variable is set from a curl_exec from another server php script. When that other server script is executed, it sends an array with url and message keys to my cloud9 server. And AS SOON as that happens, the cloud9 server executes the if isset statement. This implies it is sitting there waiting for the variable to be set??

Comment: sorry for the auto fill in im on a friend's computer